# Error in the below Program ( Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters)

Tags: java, string, stack

Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

Example 1:

Input: "abcabcbb"

Output: 3

Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.

I have tried the above problem with stack but it was not able to pass all the test cases.

```
 public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
        Stack<Character> stk = new Stack<>();
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            if(stk.isEmpty() || (!stk.contains(s.charAt(i)))){
                stk.push(s.charAt(i));
            }
            else{
                int size = stk.size();
                if(size > result){
                    result = size;
                }
                stk.clear();
                stk.push(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
               return result;
    }
```

I am getting error for the below test case.

Input: " "

Output: 0

Expected: 1

Comment: How do you pass in the `String s` - do you perform any operations on it? Like `s.trim()` ?

Comment: how is "abc" longer than "cab" ?

Comment: Most of the time it is best to test the edge cases, like an empty string or a string with only 1 char, first before starting the actual code algorithm.

Comment: If input is `ababc`, then upon finding the 2nd `a`, you clear the stack and start again. Since there are no duplicates in the remainder of the input, the `else` clause is never entered again, and upon the end of the loop, the stack has size 3, but **you never look at the remainder**. You need to repeat this code *after* the loop: `int size = stk.size(); if (size > result) { result = size; }`

Comment: *FYI:* Your logic is flawed. You cannot clear the stack when finding a duplicate. E.g. if input is `abcadefa`, you find 2nd `a` and set `result = 3` (you found `abc`). You then find 3rd `a` and update `result = 4` (you found `adef`). But what about `bcadef` with size 6? Re-think your logic.

Comment: Got it @Andreas. Thanks.

Comment: No. I didn't used trim @almac777. I just passed the string input from main.